# App receives BOOT_COMPLETED several times and Alarms are recreated again

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I have done an app as tutorial to learn how to restart deleted alarms after phone is rebooted. After reboot BroadcastReceiver receives BOOT_COMPLETED action and launches a service, which restarts all alarms. Alarms create notification when they are called. After first tests I have received notifications at expected time and then forgot about this tutorial app and didn't turn the phone off.

However, I'm still getting notifications on my screen as if the app has restarted alarms again. During the day I have received twice and all of them are unclear why. The only thing that may launch the restarting alarms is BOOT_COMPLETED action. What's going wrong here?

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.marat.recyclerviewtutorial">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity

    // list of activities

    <service android:name=".BootService"/>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>

    <receiver android:name=".RestartAlarmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**RestartAlarmsReceiver.java**

```
public class RestartAlarmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "myTag";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
        ComponentName service = context.startService(i);

        if (null == service) {
            // something really wrong here
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start service ");
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Successfully started service ");
        }

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received unexpected intent " + intent.toString());
    }
}
}
```

**BootService.java**

```
public class BootService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "myTag";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    Database db = new Database(this);
    db.open();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    data = db.getData();
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "db is openned");

    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {

        Intent notif = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        notif.putExtra("Text", data.get(i).get(2));
        notif.putExtra("Position", data.get(i).get(0));

        int sec = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(3));

        Log.d(TAG, "intent is openned");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(0)), notif, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (sec * 1000), pendingIntent);

        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm is restarted");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "before returning service");

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

It's already huge portion of code. But if you will need other parts of my app I will include them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of `START_STICKY`. I think during the day the system closes your running Service to free resources, and `START_STICKY` forces it to restart. And on restart `onStartCommand()` is triggered again.

The decision may to use `IntentService` instead. I don't see the need of using Service here.

Comment: If you are right about the reason (`onStartCommand()` returning with START_STICKY), then the solution would be to check the intent: it will be null if the service is restarted after having been killed.

Comment: at least checking Intent. But still - there is no need to keep running service here

Comment: Yes, you're right there. I think in this case I'd prefer an IntentService like you suggested. Or the service should call `stopSelf()` as soon as it is finished.

Comment: I'm new to services and don't understand your discussion :) I started googling IntentService. But could you tell me why I don't need to use `Service`? What are the reason to use `IntentService`?

Comment: IntentService finishes itself when he does some job. Service stays running. For your purpose I don't see the need to keep running Service.

Comment: Now, clear! Thanks, I will rewrite my BootService.java file and check the new behavior. Then I will let you know. Again thanks for your help)

Comment: Another question for just learning purposes. In future, if I will need to use Service in other apps, what should I return instead of `START_STICKY` to not call the service again? `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`?

Comment: You won't believe : START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: XD :) I need more experience. Will try to fill that gap